# How to add column dynamically between first and last column of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have developed a table in such a way that I can add rows and column dynamically.But issues is i want to add column between first and last column of the table, as of new columns are adding only in the last.

```js
$('#irow').click(function(){
    if($('#row').val()){
        $('#mtable tbody').append('<tr><td>Some Item</td></tr>');
        $('#mtable tbody tr:last td:first').html($('#row').val());
    }else{alert('Enter Text');}
});
$('#icol').click(function(){
    if($('#col').val()){
        $('#mtable tr').append($("<td>"));
        $('#mtable thead tr>td:last').html($('#col').val());
        $('#mtable tbody tr').each(function(){$(this).children('td:last').append($('<input type="text">'))});
    }else{alert('Enter Text');}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" id="mtable" class="table table-striped table-hover individual">
    <thead><tr><td>Employee \department</td><td>Mandatory</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table><br/><br/>
<input id="row" placeholder="Enter Employee Name"/><button id="irow">Add Board</button><br/><br/>
<input id="col" placeholder="Enter department Name"/><button id="icol">Add Subject</button>
```

I want new columns between "Employee" and "Mandatory" columns.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always appending, which will either put it inside `tr` tag as last `td`, or inside `td` tag as another one. My suggestion would be to insert the new element. For example:

```js
$('#irow').click(function(){
    if($('#row').val()){
        $('#mtable tbody').append('<tr><td>Some Item</td></tr>');
        $('#mtable tbody tr:last td:first').html($('#row').val());
    }else{alert('Enter Text');}
});
$('#icol').click(function(){
    if($('#col').val()){
        var newCol = jQuery('<td/>', {
            text: $('#col').val()
        }).insertAfter('#mtable thead tr td:first');

        $('#mtable tbody tr').each(function(){$(this).children('td:last').append($('<input type="text">'))});
    }else{alert('Enter Text');}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="mtable" class="table table-striped table-hover individual">
    <thead><tr><td>Employee \department</td><td>Mandatory</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table><br/><br/>
<input id="row" placeholder="Enter Employee Name"/><button id="irow">Add Board</button><br/><br/>
<input id="col" placeholder="Enter department Name"/><button id="icol">Add Subject</button>
```

Notice the changes. New `newCol` `td` element is added, with your value, and it's inserted after your first column:

```
if($('#col').val()){
    var newCol = jQuery('<td/>', {
        text: $('#col').val()
    }).insertAfter('#mtable thead tr td:first');
```

Also, if you want to reverse order you can switch to:

```
.insertBefore('#mtable thead tr td:last');
```

which will add new columns before the last column. You should explain what do you want with this code:

```
$('#mtable tbody tr').each(function(){$(this).children('td:last').append($('<input type="text">'))}
```